# How to get value from React Native input field?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a login form component with the following state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { email: '', password: '', error: '' };

    this.handleOnPress = this.handleOnPress.bind(this);
  }
```

`handleOnPress` simply logs `this.state.email`, like so:

```
  handleOnPress() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;

    console.log(email);
  }
```

I have a custom Input component:

```
  <Input
    value={this.state.email}
    placeholder="email@gmail.com"
    onChange={email => this.setState({ email })}
    label="Email"
  />
```

Defined like so:

```
  <TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    autoCorrect={autoCorrect}
    secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
  />
```

So when tap the button, this is what is logged in the console:

`Proxy {dispatchConfig: {…}, _targetInst: FiberNode, isDefaultPrevented: ƒ, isPropagationStopped: ƒ, _dispatchListeners: null, …}`

Shouldn't the value of the input field be logged, instead of the above object? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I was using the wrong prop. Should have been `onChangeText` instead of `onChange`, as `onChangeText` accepts an argument to the callback.

Answer (score 1):

you need to do this

```
onChange={event => this.setState({ email:event.target.value })}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer using `onChangeText`, slightly less code to write :)